# How can I find the torque of a DC 6V brushed motor in a hair trimmer?

Tags: power, torque

How to find hair trimmer motor start torque and power for a DC 6V 6000 RPM motor?

Comment: if the maker wont' tell you, measure it.

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free design house or homework-answering service. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've already done as much as you possibly could - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. This is one line, expecting mountains of effort from other people but none yourself. It's a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. Please edit your question to show your own work, own conclusions and own findings in considerable detail. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Again, welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Given a 6V, 6000RPM motor, it is easy to compute the motor speed constant Kv. Convert this to SI units (radians/second per volt) and invert it to get the torque constant Kt (Nm/Amp).

(Note that Volt*Amp = Nm * radians/sec = power),

This is only approximate as the true Kv will be somewhat higher - maybe 20% higher, and thus Kt will be lower by the same amount. This reflects the torque lost turning the motor itself, overcoming its internal friction.

Now measure the operating current under all conditions you're interested in : multiplying by Kt gives you the torque.

You can also get the stall current by measuring the DC resistance of the motor : rotate the shaft a few times and choose the lowest resistance, to eliminate errors from the brushes. Then calculate the stall current from Ohm's Law and the supply voltage, and hence the stall (starting) torque.

Answer (score 0):

Identifying parameters may be "difficult" and not very precise, if you do not own some "measurement" systems (parameters are not really "constant").

Other mean (there is also some "tips and tricks") is "simulating" and "evaluating" parameters by behavior "comparison".

This is the DC_motor (brush) macro circuit "equivalent". [microcap v12](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm)

[image]

Electrical parameters (Ra, La) can be obtained when the motor is mechanically locked (fast test !, just simplifying the equations accordingly), or with the electrical transient when power is just switched on or off.

[image]

Other parameters can be known while changing "mechanical" parameters, for example, add just an "inertia disk" which inertia is known. Some can be known within "steady state" conditions.

[image]